# Recursive function in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a project in Node JS with Typescript in which I am creating a function to check that a file exists, this check returns a boolean.

I have another function timeOut() to wait a while before checking that it has arrived, when it checks if it is true the process continues, if it is false I need it to check again if the file exists after the defined time

This is what I have:

```js
function sleepTimeout(interval) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, interval);
  });
};

async function testData(data) {

  await sleepTimeout(2000);

  if (data == false) {
    console.log('KO')
  } else {
    console.log('OK')
  }

}

testData(true)
```

It only does a check, how can I make the function redo the if after the timeOut until the boolean is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `async/await` to make sure the function is done before starting again, and a `while` loop :

```
async function testData(data) {
  while (!data) {
    await sleepTimeout(2000);
    data = await checkFileExists(); // replace this with your function to check if the file exists
  }
  console.log('OK');
}

testData(checkFileExists());
```

Comment: It's not very DRY to repeat the function that you pass to `testData` inside `testData`.

Comment: This is not repeating since it is a function call

Comment: I can see `checkFileExists` twice. Fits my definition of "repeat". Here is a quick test whether it's DRY: if I want to change that to `checkDirectoryExists` how many calls do I need to change? One (no repetition) or more than one?

Comment: Yes, but the idea here is to relaunch a function if a condition is not valid. If not this way, how would you do this ?

Comment: By only using the function once. Either it's called once inside the `testData` or, better yet, the function takes a callback. Which allows you to re-use `testData` for any other calls that need to check something over a period. Although then it's partially reimplementing `setInterval` but it's probably worth it.

Comment: Can you propose an edit of my answer ?